# How to display only 5 images with load more features using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a list but I want to display only 5 in first-time load. When the user clicks on load more then all the images will display. How can I do this?

My Code:-

```js
 $('.photos-list').hide();
 $('.photos-list').slice(1, 5).show();
    
$('#loadAllImages').click(function(){
 $('.photos-list').show();
});
```

```css
   .photos-list ul,
            .videos-list ul {
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px;
            }
            
            .photos-list ul li,
            .videos-list ul li {
                list-style: none;
                float: left;
                width: 18%;
                margin: 5px;
                position: relative;
            }
            
            .photos-list ul li img,
            .videos-list ul li img {
                width: 100%;
                border-radius: 10px;
                height: 110px;
            }
            
            .photos-list ul li span,
            .videos-list ul li span {
                position: absolute;
                bottom: 0;
                right: 0;
                background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
                padding: 5px 10px;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
            
            .photos-list ul li span svg,
            .videos-list ul li span svg {
                color: #fff;
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="photos-list">
<ul>
<li> <img src="https://picsum.photos/200"/></li>
<li> <img src="https://picsum.photos/200"/></li>
<li> <img src="https://picsum.photos/200"/></li>
<li> <img src="https://picsum.photos/200"/></li>
<li> <img src="https://picsum.photos/200"/></li>
<li> <img src="https://picsum.photos/200"/></li>
<li> <img src="https://picsum.photos/200"/></li>
<li> <img src="https://picsum.photos/200"/></li>
<li> <img src="https://picsum.photos/200"/></li>
<li> <img src="https://picsum.photos/200"/></li>
</ul>
<button type="button" id="loadAllImages">Load all Images</button>
</div>
```

ThankYou for your Efforts!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a class to hide each element, then a conditional to check the index is lower than 5, then remove the hidden class. Then an event to check click on your button and remove the hidden class from all on click.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const maxLoad = 5

  function showEl(el) {
    return el.removeClass('hidden')
  }

  $('li').each(function(index) {
    index < maxLoad ?
      showEl($(this)) : null
  })

  $('#loadAllImages').click(function() {
    $('li').each(function() {
      showEl($(this))
    })
  })
});
```

```css
.photos-list ul,
.videos-list ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.photos-list ul li,
.videos-list ul li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  width: 18%;
  margin: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

.photos-list ul li img,
.videos-list ul li img {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 110px;
}

.photos-list ul li span,
.videos-list ul li span {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  padding: 5px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.photos-list ul li span svg,
.videos-list ul li span svg {
  color: #fff;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="photos-list">
  <ul>
    <li class="hidden"> <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" /></li>
    <li class="hidden"> <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" /></li>
    <li class="hidden"> <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" /></li>
    <li class="hidden"> <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" /></li>
    <li class="hidden"> <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" /></li>
    <li class="hidden"> <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" /></li>
    <li class="hidden"> <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" /></li>
    <li class="hidden"> <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" /></li>
    <li class="hidden"> <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" /></li>
    <li class="hidden"> <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" /></li>
  </ul>
  <button type="button" id="loadAllImages">Load all Images</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The images should be dynamically added to the list when the user requests them. In the following demo, I use the same image in the array.

```js
let allImages = ['https://picsum.photos/300/100', 'https://picsum.photos/300/100', 'https://picsum.photos/300/100', 'https://picsum.photos/300/100', 'https://picsum.photos/300/100', 'https://picsum.photos/300/100', 'https://picsum.photos/300/100', 'https://picsum.photos/300/100', 'https://picsum.photos/300/100', 'https://picsum.photos/300/100']



function addImages(start, end) {

   let myList = document.getElementById('myList');   
      
   for (let i = start; i <= end; i++) {
   
     let image = document.createElement('img');
     image.src = allImages[i];
     let listItem = document.createElement('li').appendChild(image);
     
     myList.appendChild(listItem)
      
   }

}


addImages(0, 4);
```

```html
<ul id="myList">

</ul>

<input type="button" value="More" onClick="addImages(5, 9)">
```

Answer (score 0):

the best way is:

1. Place all images in a folder with public access
2. Write a JS script that use AJAX for send request to server
3. From the server, return a JSON response that contain image(s) url
4. Set an click event listener for "Show More" button that create img elements with js

**NOTE:** server response must be paginate to be standard

but if you want use just JS without backend just for testing, you can use @charlie method that support Step 4 and is a **Standard Method**.